Batter out even though his feet and body were well over the popping crease
In today’s Hundred match (4 August) between the men of  Northern superchargers and Manchester Originals Phil Salt of Manchester Originals was given out run out for not grounding his bat even though he had clearly crossed the popping crease so his feet were grounded. The Laws governing this refer to the batter being out of his/her ground if no part of the  bat OR person is grounded behind the popping crease, so why was he given out?

At the moment the bails are removed, no part of the batter Salt's body or bat were in contact with the ground behind the popping crease, nor had they been grounded and subsequently lifted as required by Law 30.1.2. This is visible in slow-motion replays.
As such, the batter is out, Run out under Law 38.1 without any exception to apply.


